# Building .net standard application that references Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, msbuild, .net-standard-2.0

I am trying to port a Windows.Forms application to .Net Standard 2.0 using Visual Studio Code. Based on responses to an earlier question (thank you guys), my plan is to try to use Xamarin.Forms to replace System.Windows.Forms. So, I add the Xamarin.Forms package to my project. When I try to run dotnet build, then I see the following error:

```
C:\Users\<user>\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\2.4.0.38779\build\netstandard1.0\Xamarin.Forms.targets(51,3): error MSB4062: The "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.FixedCreateCSharpManifestResourceName" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\<user>\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\2.4.0.38779\build\netstandard1.0\Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
```

I have tried to add various other Microsoft.Build packages but nothing seems to work. Is there a way forward here? Here's my current csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<PropertyGroup>
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="log4net" Version="2.0.8" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build" Version="15.3.409" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Framework" Version="15.3.409" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core" Version="15.3.409" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core" Version="15.3.409" />
<PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.8.1" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Configuration" Version="2.0.5" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel" Version="1.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="2.4.0.38779" />
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I think that I may be asking the same question as here: [Where is the difference of dotnet build on cmd vs VS2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46128284/where-is-the-difference-of-dotnet-build-on-cmd-vs-vs2017) but am not sure.

Comment: You've chosen `netcoreapp2.0`. This is not the same as `netstandard2.0`

Comment: Yes, I actually tried both (netcoreapp2.0 and netstandard2.0), but both report the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms application and I'm migrating my libraries from PCL to NetStandard.

It seems that you can build the project with MsBuild.exe (I used C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe).

I found it mentioned in this blog post: https://oren.codes/2017/04/23/using-xamarin-forms-with-net-standard-vs-2017-edition/

> You will need to use MSBuild.exe to build this, either on Windows with a VS 2017 command prompt or a Mac with Visual Studio for Mac. You cannot use dotnet build for these projects types. dotnet build only supports .NET Standard, .NET Core and .NET Framework project types. It is not able to build the Xamarin projects and the custom tasks in Xamarin Forms have not yet been updated to support .NET Core.

An additional note: I had to delete AssemblyInfo.cs, otherwise MsBuild complained about duplicate properties.